# Is there an elegant solution for selecting between callable and non-callable type in a Variadic Template in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I'm implementing simple text formatter for a class. The main function in it could receive a list of values that will be concatenated. Or optionally, for cases where the parameters are not friends of ostream, I accept a conversion function as first parameter that will convert all other parameters into a std::string.

The following code shows the idea, but it does not compile. For simplicity, I will output to cout in the example.

```
struct formater{
    template<typename P, typename... PS>
    void format(const P& p, const PS&... ps){
        if (std::is_convertible<P, std::function<void()>>::value){
            cout << p(ps...) << endl;
        } else {
            cout << p;
            log(ps...);
        }
    }
};
```

The reason the code does not compile is, if P is callable, it will not be possible to output it to cout in the "else" branch, and if P is not callable, it will tell P is not callable and cannot receive ps... parameters in the "then" branch.

I thought to use enable_if, but since I'm defining both cases (T and F) of the condition, I get redefinition of same function and also fail to compile.

I could try to mimic static_if, but it doesn't look elegant at all.

I'm wondering if there is some elegant way to check that P is callable and SFINAE it. Maybe exploiting that I know the parameter types of P,  (PS...)->std::string.

Comment: I assume `PARAM` is supposed to be `P`?

Comment: Do you want to know whether `PARAM` is callable with `const PS&...` specifically, or just whether `PARAM` is callable at all (i.e. it is a function pointer or a function object)?

Comment: In this particular scenario I will like the first option. Anyway, I'm curious about the second one for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems. First, just like you said, an if is a runtime branch only, and second, you are not checking for an object to be callable, but you are checking if an object is callable with no arguments. Any callable object that must take arguments won't pass your test.

I would first implement that trait. Note that this is not necessary for C++17:

```
template<typename, typename = void>
struct is_callable : std::false_type {};

template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_callable<F(Args...), void_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then, you can use `std::enable_if`:

```
struct Formatter {
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    auto format(F func, Args&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<is_callable_v<F(Args...)>> {
        std::cout << func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto format(T&& value) -> std::enable_if_t<!is_callable_v<T()>> {
        std::cout << std::forward<T>(value);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You can implement `void_t` like this:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

You can go check this live example: <kbd>[Live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f9c426e4515fe6d)</kbd>

Please note that in C++17, you have the constexpr if and `std::is_invocable`:

```
struct Formatter {
    template<typename F, typename... Args
    void format(F&& param, Args&&... args) {
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>) {
            std::cout << std::invoke(std::forward<F>(param), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            std::cout << std::forward<F>(param);
            log(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The first solution, it is not 100% c++14 (void_t is c++17). However, I tried it using c++1z support and had to make small changes to make it compile.

Here I pasted an example with the changes: https://pastebin.com/jfPzX8yi

The example compiles, but the result is not the expected one:
I want to obtain 1, Passing test and Hey. And I get 1, Passing test, 1.

About the if-constexpr. Making a call "formatter f; f.format(1)" does not compile with following error:

error: type 'PS' of function parameter pack does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs

Comment: The implementation of void_t makes the trick for compiling in c++14, however still getting the wrong result on the example. 
When "auto fs_no_param = []()->std::string { return "HEY"; };" It is casted as value and "1" is output in place of "HEY". :(

Comment: I just noticed the second overload is taking only a single T, thats why there is conflict with functions of no params. SFINAE is resolving on the quantity of params only. If I extend to T... there it becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @dvicino I ended up creating a trait for that. See my edits.

Comment: Great, I had to make a small change to make it fully work (you constrained the T in the second case to be a single one). Pasted here the example with one more test and the edit for making it work: https://pastebin.com/U95AK28c
I'm accepting this answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::enable_if`:

```
struct formater{
    template<typename P, typename... PS>
    std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<PARAM, std::function<void(PS...)>>::value, void>::type
    format(const PARAM& p, const PS&... ps){
        cout << p(ps...) << endl;

    }

    template<typename P, typename... PS>
    std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<PARAM, std::function<void(PS...)>>::value, void>::type
    format(const PARAM& p, const PS&... ps){
        cout << p;
        log(ps...);

    }
};
```

Comment: The test with `std::function` is not right as it's should be taking parameters. Change it to `std::function<void(PS...)>`

Comment: I make the following full version of the example for testing using the enable if approach.

https://pastebin.com/fJp3LWx1

It does not compile, second call tries to still go to concatenation (using clang).

Comment: But... it seems to work flawlessly. Just a typo in the lambda... Check [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3kkLegDWEDpQNWZC).